# Lost in translation - encoding

Tags: java, encoding, java-me, utf-8, websphere

I am currently trying to process a http post request from a **J2me** application to a **Websphere 6** server which communicates with other systems via MQ messaging. The Queue character set is **Cp037** and the message retrieved from the queue is **Cp1256**.

Everything works fine up to the point where I try to send a response in Arabic to the j2me client as such:

```
String respStr = new String(orginalMsg, "Cp1256");
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

The reponse from the servlet is set with:

- **Character Encoding:** UTF-8
- **Content Type:** text/plain;charset=UTF-8

I subsequently read the response in J2me with:

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connFact.getInputConnection(),"UTF-8");  
buffer = new StringBuffer((int) length); // If no length, default to 256 buffer
char[] data = new char[128];
int total = 0x00;
int read = -1;
do
{
    read = inputStreamReader.read(data);
    if (read > 0x00)
    {
        total += read;
        buffer.append(data, 0x00, read);
    }
} while (read != -1 && !cancel);
```

I am running the code in the WTK emulator which I know supports UTF-8 arabic characters as I can display harcoded strings on a form.

However when it comes to display the result from the response only ? characters are displayed.

I have tried to do the conversion programmatically instead of letting Websphere do the implicit conversion but I get the same result.

---

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a beautiful article that could help you - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I just watched it yesterday. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0335266/

Comment: Please tell us where `bytes` in the first code fragment come from?

Comment: bytes comes from a JMS TextMessage:   bytes = txtMsg.getText().getBytes("Cp037");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, you imply that you are doing this:

```
//these bytes are Cp037 encoded
bytes = txtMsg.getText().getBytes("Cp037");
//you don't seem to be using respStr
String respStr = new String(orginalMsg, "Cp1256");
//you've told this response it is UTF-8, but the bytes are Cp037
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

If you get character data (string/char array) from the queue (`txtMsg.getText()`), set the response [content type](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) and use a [writer](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) to write the response data.

```
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
response.getWriter(txtMsg.getText());
```

The writer will transcode the UTF-16-encoded character data to UTF-8.